# React recursive nested components

Tags: reactjs, recursion, nested, react-functional-component, preact

```js
import { render } from "react";

const MyComponent = ({ count = 0, children }) => {
  return count === 1 ? null : (
    <div style={{ border: "3px solid #ccc", margin: 5 }}>
      {children}
      <MyComponent count={++count} children={children} />
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent>
        hi
        <MyComponent>
          wow
          <MyComponent> bye </MyComponent>
          <MyComponent> bye </MyComponent>
          <MyComponent> bye </MyComponent>
        </MyComponent>
      </MyComponent>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

How to resolve the above code without count props. I want to do nested components like the above. Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this?

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/preact-nested-recursive-vjrle

Comment: "Solve" in what sense? What is the issue?

Comment: I have used count which is not required here. I want to break the loop.

Comment: Break what loop?

Comment: In the recursive loop, I just made some count props which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Or to answer your question can we do recursion without using the count props used above?

Comment: It would entirely depend on *how* you're handling the render logic

Comment: @JoelHager. I want to create something like react nested routes. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Oh, I *think* I understand what you're saying, maybe--you're trying to disallow arbitrarily-deep nesting of this component?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes exactly.